# Performance and memory impact of different approaches for passing props to a child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm relatively new to React and currently learning about passing props to child components. I have a parent component called Counter and a child component called ChildComponent. My goal is to understand the performance and memory implications of different approaches for passing props to the child component.

**Parent Component (Counter.js):**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ChildComponent from './CounterChild';

const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(10);

  const getCount = () => {
    console.count('count me');
    return count * 2;
  };

  const increment = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
      <ChildComponent count={getCount()} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

**Child Component (ChildComponent.js):**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const ChildComponent = ({ count }) => {
  const [count1, setCount1] = useState(count);

  console.count('child count', count);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Child Component</h3>
      <p>Received count from parent: {count} </p>
      <p>Count From Child Logic: {count1}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChildComponent;
```

In **Approach 1**, I'm passing the prop count to ChildComponent by calling a function getCount() within the parent component and passing its return value as the prop. This function is declared inside the parent component.

In **Approach 2**, I'm declaring the function getCount() outside the component and directly using it inside the parent component. I'm passing the function itself as the prop.

In **Approach 3**, I'm passing an arrow function as the prop to ChildComponent which returns count * 2.

```
<ChildComponent count={()=> count * 2} />


const ChildComponent = ({ count }) => {
  const [count1, setCount1] = useState(count);
// rest of the code
```

In **Approach 4**, I'm directly passing the count state variable as the prop to ChildComponent and using the arrow functionn inside the useState.

```
<ChildComponent count={count} />

const ChildComponent = ({ count }) => {
 const [count1, setCount1] = useState(()=>count*2);
```

I want to understand the performance and memory implications of each approach.

- Will declaring the function inside the parent component (Approach 1) cause memory allocation on each re-render?
- What about Approach 2 where the function is declared outside the component? Will it have any performance impact?
- Is there a recommended approach  from a performance and memory standpoint ?
- Are there any React best practices for passing the data from parent to child?

I have seen React [docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) supporting the lazy initialization inside the useState() hook but still people are using functions inside the jsx.